# Как оформить "свободную лицензию" на исходный код ?

Tags: лицензирование

Написал программу сортировки (версия сортировки слиянием с "маленькой" дополнительной памятью), исходный текст которой хочу опубликовать в сети. В частности обсудить ее здесь.

Желательно, чтобы все могли ее использовать, переделывать и т.д. и никто не смог в дальнейшем запретить остальным делать это. В общем свободный source.

Читал (может не очень вдумчиво, слов всюду много) об этом, но так и на понял, какой комментарий надо поместить в начало файла с исходником и нужны ли какие-то еще действия с моей стороны.

Прошу помощи. Желательно **конкретный "шаблон"**, а не ссылки на общие указания.

---

**UPDATE 1**

Всем спасибо за ответы. Как Вы считаете, следующий текст в начале исходника - это то что нужно ?

```
/* Copyright (C) 2012 Vasily Anishchenko
   This file is part of the Yamsort.
   (Yet Another Merge Sort Routines)

   Yamsort is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    Yamsort is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with Yamsort.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

  (Этот файл — часть Yamsort.

   Yamsort - свободная программа: вы можете перераспространять ее и/или
   изменять ее на условиях Стандартной общественной лицензии GNU в том виде,
   в каком она была опубликована Фондом свободного программного обеспечения;
   либо версии 3 лицензии, либо (по вашему выбору) любой более поздней
   версии.

   Yamsort распространяется в надежде, что она будет полезной,
   но БЕЗО ВСЯКИХ ГАРАНТИЙ; даже без неявной гарантии ТОВАРНОГО ВИДА
   или ПРИГОДНОСТИ ДЛЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫХ ЦЕЛЕЙ. Подробнее см. в Стандартной
   общественной лицензии GNU.

   Вы должны были получить копию Стандартной общественной лицензии GNU
   вместе с этой программой. Если это не так, см.
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.)

 */
```

Может быть еще что-либо нужно (и где ?) добавлять ?

Comment: Когда-нибудь я буду рассказывать, что "в свое время я вступал в переписку с автором ЭТОЙ сортировки". И единичка то меня.

Comment: Спасибо @VioLet, теперь понял. Только надо еще добавить первой строчкой имя программы и в конце

Also add information on how to contact you by electronic and paper mail.

Интересно, paper mail это обязательно ?

Преобразовал Ваш комментарий в ответ, поэтому данный комментарий остался (несколько ни к месту) здесь.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Возможно вам пригодится [этот большой, может быть даже полный список всевозможных свободных лицензий](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical). И плюс вам за бескорыстие!

---------------------------------- UPDATE 10.03.2012 18:07 --------------------------------------

[[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow), [[[[@GLmonster](/users/4139/glmonster)](/users/4139/glmonster)](/users/4139/glmonster)](/users/4139/glmonster) прав насчет **GPL** - она обязывает раскрывать код проекта, в котором используется компонент, выпущенный под ней, фактически исключая тем самым возможность использования в проприетарном ПО.

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) - **GPL** больше приспособлена для какого-то идеального утопического мира, имеющим слабое отношение к нашим реалиям. Более демократичны в этом плане, например, [BSD](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_BSD) и [MIT](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_MIT) - они допускают использование в коммерческом ПО, способствуя этим увеличению сфер применения, количеству использования и, не исключено, инвестиций. Проприетарность не всегда зло.

п.с. это сообщение писалось как комментарий к высказыванию [[[[@GLmonster](/users/4139/glmonster)](/users/4139/glmonster)](/users/4139/glmonster)](/users/4139/glmonster), но у меня что-то не получилось его отправить - он просто пропал, посему пишу как ответ.

Comment: beerware нету. Не полный :)

Comment: @dword, я не отрицал сказанное про GPL и уж тем более не защищал ее ( местные в курсе:) ). Говорил о том, что непредоставление лицензии = "правам по умолчанию", а по умолчанию программа принадлежит автору, как книга, песня и т.п. и без его разрешения (пусть даже устного) с ней ничего делать нельзя.

Comment: @Sh4dow Понятно, согласен с вами, вышло недопонимание.

Comment: @dword, еще раз спасибо, вижу Вы разбираетесь в этой теме. Но я ведь не имею отношения ни к MIT, ни к Беркли ! 

Вопрос остается, он простой - **какой конкретно текст и где писать** ?

Comment: @avp - То, что вы не имеете к ним отношения - не страшно, вы все равно можете использовать эти лицензии для своего продукта. Вот тут сказано как это сделать правильно: [BSD](http://licenseit.ru/wiki/index.php/Modified_BSD_license), [MIT](http://licenseit.ru/wiki/index.php/MIT) - текста на полторы странички, там же можно взять шаблоны.

Comment: Продолжение: Единственное их отличие в том, что в **BSD** запрещается использовать ваше имя в рекламных целях без вашего согласия, в **MIT** этого пункта нет, но зато она не лицензирована, а значит вы можете дописать в нее свои пункты и назвать, к примеру, **AVP** - это достаточно распространенная практика. Юридическую силу имеет только оригинальный текст на английском, перевод можно приложить в качестве справки. Текст нужно вписать в шапку исходников и приложить в виде текстового файла.

Comment: Отлично, коротко и ясно. 

У меня (в копии исходников от  Christopher Swenson) есть такой текст. 

Просто меня смущало MIT.


Получается следующее:


    yamsort ....
licensed under the MIT Public License:

Copyright (c) 2012 ....

 Permission is hereby granted, ...

и т.д. 

Так ?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз всем, особенно Вам, @dword !

Теперь, надеюсь,  мне все ясно. Вопрос закрываю. Жаль нельзя принять еще и Ваш ответ.

Answer (score 15):

[@avp](/users/232/avp) да, это все, что от вас требуется. Внизу лицензии GNU же есть пункт "How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs".

Comment: Спасибо @VioLet, теперь понял. 

Интересно, paper mail это обязательно ?

Comment: @avp да нет, я думаю, что на сегодняшний день электронную почту можно смело считать полновесной заменой голубям и прочей Почте России.

Answer (score 11):

Я подобные проги публикую на [гугле](http://code.google.com), там же имеется несколько видов бесплатных хранилищ (svn, git, mercurial), баг-трекер, возможность выбрать конкретную лицензию (только бесплатное распространение), вики, менеджмент всего етого дела и тд. Имеется конечно масса и других подобных ресурсов, забугорных в том числе, но я предпочитаю гугл.

Comment: все нармальные патсаны публикуют на github !11OneАдЗин! =)

Comment: А все адекваты на CodePlex и чего?

Comment: Это дело вкуса, привычек и тд, "нармальность патсанов" данной хренью не определяется =)

Comment: @wind, @AlexWindHope, Вы сказали публикуете. Я сделал **UPDATE** вопроса. Там то что нужно ?

Comment: Кстати, google code закрыли.

Answer (score 10):

Совсем недавно опубиковал свой первый небольшой проект на GitHub и встал тот же самый вопрос. Так вот на самом GitHub'е есть хороша фича по добавлению файлов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

После этого в новом окне введите имя файла `LICENSE`, и система автоматически предложите вам выбрать лицензию из обширного списка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого автоматически создается файл по выбранному шаблону и  добавляется в репозиторий проекта.

Кроме этого советую не ломать голову над созданием своих лицензий, а использовать уже всем знакомые и общепринятые лицензии.

Answer (score 8):

Взять с gnu.org лицензию и запихнуть в .txt файл, что тут не понятного то?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы подобрать подходящую вам лицензию вы можете воспользоваться сайтом https://choosealicense.com/ (на английском). На нем посоветуют какую лучше лицензию выбрать исходя из ваших требований. На том же сайте есть сводная таблица с множеством лицензий https://choosealicense.com/licenses/